# Plotting a motion field with quiver in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to use a quiver plot for the first time. I have a matrix uv(2x251x251) with an uv vector associated to x and y coordinates. When I try to use

```
quiver(uv(1,:,:),uv(2,:,:))
```

I do not see anything, no points or arrows. When I try to plot just one vector for just one point with

```
quiver(uv(1,1,1),uv(2,1,1))
```

the arrow shows up and I can see it. My u and v values range from -1 to 1. I don't get why I can see something when I plot one vector but not when I try to plot all of them.

Comment: do you see a figure window with blue color when you do `quiver(uv(1,:,:),uv(2,:,:))`

Comment: no the window is just blank white

Comment: It will help us if you can upload the `uv` variable as a mat-file somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[quiver](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html) does not work with 3 dimensional arrays. Try this:

```
u = squeeze(uv(1,:,:) ;
v = squeeze(uv(2,:,:) ;
quiver(u,v)
```